# What is wrong with the use of malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I am reading a matrix from a file and have the following code:

```
int **mat;

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen("matrix.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open file \n");
        exit(1);
        getch();
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &N); //size of matrix NxN

    mat = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*)); 

    for(i = 1; i <= N; i++){
        mat[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for(j = 1; j <= N; j++)
        fscanf(fp, "%1d", &mat[i][j]);
 }

 fclose(fp);
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: We most certainly can not because you didn't provite any error messages.

Comment: The casts. Don't cast. (Also the indexing.)

Comment: Lots of things. For one, array indexes in C go from `0` to `N-1`, not `1` to `N`.

Comment: Give us a hint.  What errors are produced?

Comment: upvoted, reasonably posed question given asker's level of knowledge

Comment: @agksmehx Yes, but he could easily describe his problem instead of asking 'what is wrong?' He sure knows something is wrong, which is why he is here in the first place. He needs to describe what is wrong to get a +1.

Comment: @marlon the problem is (as stated clearly in the title) I am not using correctly malloc, which causes my program *that I compiled in devc) to crash

Comment: upvoted. StackOverflow has room for all skill levels :) including good faith effort to ask a question

Comment: Well, biggdman, nothing is really wrong with your use of `malloc`, so it doesn't help that that is stated clearly in the title. That the program crashes describes the problem you are seeing, so that is more useful. Even better would of course be to know *in which line* the program crashes, which a debugger would tell you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much ...

1. you are missing a few calls to `free`.  Every call to `malloc` should have a corresponding call to `free`.
2. Array indicies start at zero and not one
3. The call to `getch()` after `exit` is superfluous.
4. `main` is usually defined as `int main(int argc, char **argv)`
5. You are missing a return value from `main`

Answer (score 1):

For large arrays, this code is not as memory-efficient as it could be.  You can get away with one malloc of size N * N * sizeof (int).  You'd then index into it as array[N*row + col].  If that notation is too ugly, you can coat it with some syntactic sugar via a macro.

Also, what everyone else said. :)

Answer (score 0):

change to `for (i = 1; i < N; i++) { ...` and `for (j = 0; j < N; j++) { ...` because C uses 0-based indexing. i. e. the first element of an array A is A[0] (not A[1])

Answer (score 0):

Include `<stdlib.h>` -- so you don't need to cast the return from `malloc(3)`, which can mask further problems.

```
 for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
    mat[i] = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    for(j=1;j<=N;j++)
    fscanf(fp, "%1d", &mat[i][j]);
 }
```

You've busted your array indexes -- in C, arrays are indexed from `0` to `N-1`, not `1` to `N`.